# Increase Video uploading speed performance

Tags: ios

I'm using URLSession to upload recorded video file which is in .mov format. For 30 sec video it is taking so much time that my client want it to be bit faster. What should i do to increase upload speed? Thanks!

Comment: show him speed in other apps and if you find out that some apps are doing that faster, find out how they are doing that

Comment: How big are your video files? Maybe try re-encoding to make them smaller - or use a lower resolution. Are you uploading over 3G / 4G / Wifi?

Comment: @AshleyMills nearly 60M. tested on both wifi and 4g

Answer (score 3):

With a 60MB file it's not surprising it takes a long time.

If you're on 3G, The *maximum* upload speed is about 1.7 Mb/sec, so if you get about half that in real world, a 60MB file would take about 9 minutes to upload. You need to re-encode to make your file smaller.

Aim for around 1MB for a 10 second clip, so 3MB for 30 seconds, and you'll upload in about 25 seconds over 3G. Faster on 4G and Wifi obviously.

*Always* assume the worst case, and test your network connectivity using 3G.

To set a size limit, set the `fileLengthLimit` on your `AVAssetExportSession`, I'd start with a value of **100KB/second** which in your case, for a 30 second clip would give you

```
fileLengthLimit = 3000000
```

From `AVAssetExportSession.h`

> Indicates the file length that the output of the session should not exceed.  Depending on the content of the source asset, it is possible for the output to slightly exceed the file length limit.  The length of the output file should be tested if you require that a strict limit be observed before making use of the output.  See also maxDuration and timeRange.